# Is there a way to use the solution of a polynomial to approximate the solution to a similar polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Suppose I know the solution to the polynomial
$$
c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + ... + c_n x^n = 0 \hspace{15mm} (*)
$$

If I wanted to approximate the solution to the polynomial

$$
(c_0 - \delta) + c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + ... + c_n x^n = 0
$$

for some value of delta that was small relative to $c_0$, is there a way to find the approximate solution by using the known solution to polynomial $(*)$?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Newton's method, starting from the known root to the nearby equation, should work here.

Comment: I was ultimately hoping to find a closed form approximation for the solution of the second polynomial

Comment: I expect that numerical schemes are the best you'll get.  Happily, those tend to be very efficient.

Comment: You say "the solution" where I'm guessing you mean either a linear factor of the polynomial in $x$ or else the set of roots in $x$.  One difficulty is that a product of roots having more than one or two members typically has no simple mechanisms for absorbing a constant offset.

Comment: @lulu numerical schemes *are* closed form approximations.  They are sometimes exact in the limit, but simply truncating them at an arbitrary depth is closed-form and also an approximation.  NN2's answer illustrates this.  Also "two iterations of Newton's method" is a closed form approximation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's define the function
$$f(x) = c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + ... + c_n x^n$$

And $\bar{x}$ is a solution of the equation
$$-c_0 = f(x) \tag{1}$$
With $\delta \ll c_0$, we expect that the solution of
$$-c_0 - \delta= f(x)\tag{2}$$
is very closed to $\bar{x}$. Then, we can suppose that the solution of $(2)$ is $(\bar{x}+\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon$ is small ( $\epsilon \sim o(1)$ ).

From $(1),(2)$, we have
$$-\delta= f(\bar{x}+\epsilon)-f(\bar{x}) \tag{3}$$

With the first order Taylor approximation, we have
$$\begin{align}
-\delta &= f(\bar{x}+\epsilon)-f(\bar{x}) \\
 &\approx (\bar{x}+\epsilon) -\bar{x}) f'(\bar{x}) )+ o(\epsilon^2) \\
 &\approx \epsilon f'(\bar{x}) ) \\
\end{align}
$$
So,
$$\epsilon  \approx \frac{-\delta}{f'(\bar{x})} = \frac{-\delta}{\sum_{i=1}^n ic_i\bar{x}^{(i-1)}}$$

and the closed-form solution of $(2)$ is $(\bar{x}+\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the implicit function $$f(x)=c_0 +\sum_ {k=1}^n c_k\,  x^k  = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial c_0}=1$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}=\sum_ {k=1}^n k\,c_k\, x^{k-1}$$
$$\frac {dx}{dc_0}=-\frac{\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial c_0} } {\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} }=-\frac 1{\sum_ {k=1}^n k\,c_k\, x^{k-1} }$$ Going to $\Delta$'s, for any root
$$\Delta x=-\frac {\Delta c_0}{\sum_ {k=1}^n k\,c_k\, x^{k-1} }$$